# Differential Equations (Application)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A tank, with a rectangular base and having vertical sides of height $h$, is initially full of water.  The water leaks out of a small hole in the horizontal base of the tank at a rate which, at any time instant, is proportional to the square root of the depth of the water at the instant.  If $x$ is the depth of the water at time $t$ after the leak started, write down a differential equation connecting $x$ and $t$.  If the tank is exactly half empty after one hour, find the further time that elapses before the tank becomes completely empty.

I found that the differential equation is $\frac{dx}{dt}=-k\sqrt{x}$. My answer is $2+\sqrt{2}$ hours but the given answer in book is $1+\sqrt{2}$ hours. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: Did you subtract the one hour it took to get to half?

Comment: I've found my mistake already. The answer in book is correct.